# php DirectoryIterator sort files by date

Tags: php, file, sorting

I'm using php's `DirectoryIterator` class to list files in a directory. I can't however figure out an easy way to sort files by date. How is this done with DirectoryIterator

```
<?php
 $dir = new DirectoryIterator('.');
  foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {     
     echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . '<br>';
   }
?>
```

What if i name my files like whatever_2342345345.ext where the numbers represents time in milliseconds so each file has a unique number. How can we sort by looking at the numbers after underscore

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you need to sort, build an array and sort that.

```
$files = array();
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('.');
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {     
   $files[$fileinfo->getMTime()][] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
}

ksort($files);
```

This will build an array with the modified time as the key and an array of filenames as the value. It then sorts via [`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php), which will give you the filenames in order of time modified.

If you then want to re-flatten the structure to a standard array, you can use...

```
$files = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $files);
```

Comment: I have to say that you're little wrong saying "An iterator exists to do just that, iterate.". Iterators by their nature could add filterting and ordering features. Indeed, the aim of iterator is to provide interface to iterate, but this definition doesn't restrict iterator to do some internal jobs with the data.

Comment: The example you provided is not working for me. Did you try it. What if i name my files like whatever_2342345345.ext where the numbers represents time where each file have a unique number. How can we sort by looking at the numbers after underscore

Comment: @Pinkie: I didn't try it, but the theory should be correct. What error did you get? Are you looking at `$files`?

Comment: @Pinkie: you **have to** specify all what-if's in the question, **before** SO answerers have spent time answering your question (which actually doesn't contain significant details)

Comment: if i do `print_r($files)`, i am able to see the array. Do we need another loop to echo out the array

Comment: @Pinkie: sure. It is a good practice to separate data extraction/processing logic from output (presentation) logic

Comment: @zerkms  i agree. I added this to the question. My files are already named with `_time` so i either need to sort based on the number in each file after the underscore, or use array as Alex specified.

Comment: @Pinkie: well - you need to write your own comparison function and use `usort`. It is really easy

Comment: This works. Doing a foreach after ksorting displayed the files sorted by getMTime(). I wish DirectoryIterator had more function as to see what what files were last uploaded and then sort accordingly.

Comment: And how to sort without raising memory usage? Thats the real benefit of DirectoryIterator compared to glob.

Comment: there's a problem with this, what if more than 1 file have the same getMTime ? I know it's hard it can happen but not impossible

Comment: @aleation Adjust the answer accordingly to your situation. Perhaps have each key point to an array of files.

Comment: -1 Because it could result in certain files being left off the list. Also, as a side note, relying on the filesystem's date-modified is inherently unreliable unless all of the files are known to have been modified whilst on the host computer.

Comment: @CommaToast I'm gonna fix it.

Comment: OK +1 :D I see what you did there.

Comment: 1+... Thanks for your code. Answered so many questions just add my thank you comment here. Really Appreciate your help for community.

Comment: I think `$files[$fileinfo->getMTime() . $file->getFilename()] = ` is a bit easier, doesn't require the final `array_merge()`, and has the added benefit of a secondary sort by name.

Answer (score 5):

If you still want to access all the data available at `DirectoryIterator` (e.g. `isDot()` `getSize()` etc) a possible way is to store the Iterator key on the array you are going to sort, and seek the `DirectoryIterator` later.

```
$sorted_keys = array();
$dir_iterator = new DirectoryIterator('.');

foreach ( $dir_iterator as $fileinfo )
{
    $sorted_keys[$fileinfo->getMTime()] = $fileinfo->key();
}

ksort($sorted_keys);

/* Iterate `DirectoryIterator` as a sorted array */
foreach ( $sorted_keys as $key ) 
{
    $dir_iterator->seek($key);
    $fileinfo = $dir_iterator->current();

    /* Use $fileinfo here as a normal DirectoryIterator */
    echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . '  ' . $fileinfo->getSize() . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: While using keys, high possibilities of a problem discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875126/array-ksort-only-shows-non-like-values

Answer (score 2):

In case multiple files have the same modified time (updated):

```
$files = array();
$mtimes = array();
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('.');
foreach($dir as $file){
  if(!$file->isFile())
    continue;

  $mtime = $file->getMTime();

  if(!$mtimes[$mtime]){
    $files[$mtime.'.0'] = $file->getFilename();
    $mtimes[$mtime] = 1;
  }else{
    $files[$mtime.'.'.$mtimes[$mtime]++] = $file->getFilename();
  }
}

ksort($files);
```

Comment: Two files/folders with the same time causes the issue discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875126/array-ksort-only-shows-non-like-values & your solution worked for my situation.