# Get the newest file from directory structure year/month/date/time

Tags: php

I store backups of databases in a directory structure

year/month/day/time/backup_name

an example would be

basics_mini/2012/11/05/012232/RATIONAL.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.20110505004037.001 basics_mini/2012/11/06/012251/RATIONAL.0.db2inst1.NODE0000.20110505003930.001

note that timestamp from the backup file cannot be used. Before the automation testing starts the server time is set to 5.5.2011

So the question is how I can get the latest file if I pass the "base directory" (basics_mini) to some function that I am going to code. My thoughts are that I list the base directory and sort by time to get the year. Then I do the same for month, day and time.

I wonder if there is any "easier" solution to that in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can fetch whole directory tree at once and get last elem from it:

```
$baseFolder = './backup_mini' ;

$arr = glob("{$baseFolder}/*/*/*/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$lastDir = array_pop($arr);
```

Comment: Beautiful. I modified your code to `$arr = glob("{$baseFolder}/*/*/*/*/*");` and I get exactly what I want. One more question. Is it glob array sorted automatically the way I need it by default or I better sort it?

Comment: Since there is `GLOB_NOSORT` flag, I'm assuming that result is already sorted

Comment: It is sorted, I just wanted to be 100% sure :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any amazingly simple one-liner but it looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642191/php-directoryiterator-sort-files-by-date) might be helpful:

```
$files = array();
$flags = FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_SELF;
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/path/to/basics_mini', $flags);
foreach ($dir as $path) {
    if ($path->isFile()) {
        $files[$path->getPath()] = $path->getFilename();
    }
}

ksort($files);
```

You might want to use a [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) because your directory structure is a little more complex.
The [`FilesystemIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php#filesystemiterator.constants) constants can also be helpful.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your code but the file time cannot be used to find out the correct backup. Only the directories names.

Comment: oh well. got you wrong about that. revised my code above (`getPath()` instead of `getMTime()`).

Comment: this is not valid - as each element in the loop will only contain private methods

Comment: steven, would you please elaborate? i'm not getting what you're saying.