# What determines the order of PHP's FilesystemIterator and can I change it?

Tags: php, file, loops, iteration

To iterate with PHP over files in a directory I do

```
$it = new FilesystemIterator('/path/of/files/to/iterate/over');
foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
  echo $fileinfo->getFilename();
}
```

But what is the order here that files are processed? I did some tests but I can't seem to understand the order PHP is using. It's the same order everytime, at least, but it is neither alphabetically, mtime, ctime or atime. I tried this by creating some empty files with different names, they were neither shown in their chronological creation order nor sorted alphabetically.

**What order does FilesystemIterator use? And Why? Can I change the order?**

Comment: It's probably just the order of the entries in the directory file. This is loosely related to the order that the files were originally created, but as files get deleted, new files may take their place. But it's not predictable, and not changeable without copying the entire directory.

Comment: It has "no sorting" order by default - so it's determined by file system itself. And - no, this can not be changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As told here [DirectoryIterator sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642191/php-directoryiterator-sort-files-by-date), an iterator iterates. You will need to build an array and sort it.

An iterator is a desing pattern used to traverse elements on a container. More here: [Iterator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern)

Comment: But an iterator has to get its returned data from somewhere. And this "somewhere" must have some order (changable or not). That was my question actually. ;)

Comment: Yes, but the iterator doesn't order by itself. Use iterator_to_array with FilesystemIterator as argument and then sort the resulting array.

Comment: Thanks, with this comment I'll accept the answer. :)